# fill line up to specific length regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is part of a list. All lines need to be filled up with zeros up to 12 characters at the start of each line. Some lines already are length 12...

```
801095126710
2227121
19472168
21521070
21945110
25260089
92000077
93400015
132300300
132405100
211304212
934000107
934000108
934000110
934000120
934000144
93400138
160908013840
822100052908
822100053358
```

How can this be done with regex?

Comment: You want to change f.e. 93400138 to 000000000000 or
93400138 -> 000093400138?

Comment: adding zeros. not replacing. so yes 000093400138

Comment: As Thomas Ayoub stated, doing math with regex is not really possible. This would be really simple and easy to do with a simple script and I would suggest looking into that if this is a larger, reoccurring problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning** this is ugly.

You can look for:

```
^(.{0,11})$
```

and replace with `0$1`. Click on <kbd>replace all</kbd> 11 times and *voilà.*

---

You *can't* do math with regex. Regex are for string matching.

Comment: Could You explain me this 0$1? I'm not that advanced in regex, and it bothers from time. Like how to find some pattern and change it to 1084...this_pattern"hello world"

Comment: `0` means, well `0`. `$1` means *the value from the first capturing group* @MichałM

Comment: So if I have (\d+)(\w+)(\!@#$%^&) to find (special characters of course with '\'), to replace it with \w+ I need to put $2?

Comment: @MichałM it's a bit vague and out of the context, but if I understand correctly, yes

Comment: I'm learning - of course it's out of the context. I have just tested it and i understand it now. Not so difficult. Thanks!

Comment: This is a rather cleaver approach.

Comment: works great! you say its ugly. i say imperfections are beautiful

Answer (score 1):

## Description

I see this as a two step process. Step One insert 12 `0` at the beginning of each line. Step Two capture the last 12 characters and all leading `0`, and replace with just the 12 captured characters.

---

## Step One - Replace commas with 10 spaces

```
^
```

**Replace with:** `000000000000`

**Live Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/rM8bK2/1

**Sample Text**

```
801095126710
2227121
19472168
21521070
21945110
25260089
92000077
93400015
132300300
132405100
211304212
934000107
934000108
934000110
934000120
934000144
93400138
160908013840
822100052908
822100053358
```

**After Replacement**

```
000000000000801095126710
0000000000002227121
00000000000019472168
00000000000021521070
00000000000021945110
00000000000025260089
00000000000092000077
00000000000093400015
000000000000132300300
000000000000132405100
000000000000211304212
000000000000934000107
000000000000934000108
000000000000934000110
000000000000934000120
000000000000934000144
00000000000093400138
000000000000160908013840
000000000000822100052908
000000000000822100053358

123456789,123456789,123456789
```

<sub>Note: I inserted the number line here to help illustrate the number and position of characters</sub>

---

## Step Two - Capture 10 characters and all trailing spaces

```
0*([0-9]{12})$
```

**Replace with:** `$1`

**Live Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/aS2xG0/1

**Sample Text**

Because this is step two, the sample text is the output from step one above

```
000000000000801095126710
0000000000002227121
00000000000019472168
00000000000021521070
00000000000021945110
00000000000025260089
00000000000092000077
00000000000093400015
000000000000132300300
000000000000132405100
000000000000211304212
000000000000934000107
000000000000934000108
000000000000934000110
000000000000934000120
000000000000934000144
00000000000093400138
000000000000160908013840
000000000000822100052908
000000000000822100053358
```

**After Replacement**

```
801095126710
000002227121
000019472168
000021521070
000021945110
000025260089
000092000077
000093400015
000132300300
000132405100
000211304212
000934000107
000934000108
000934000110
000934000120
000934000144
000093400138
160908013840
822100052908
822100053358      
123456789,123456789,
```

<sub>Note: I inserted the number line here to help illustrate the number and position of characters</sub>